# Update field in INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql-update, foreign-keys, inner-join, crud

I want to update field with inner join relation
I tried to remove inner join relation and it worked for some column, but didnt work on foreign key (the foreign key didnt change)

```
UPDATE products 
INNER JOIN categories 
        ON products.category_id = categories.category_id 
SET product_name = '$product_name', 
    product_price = '$product_price', 
    category_id = '$category_id' 
WHERE product_id = $product_id
```

Comment: There is no case that an UPDATE statement updates only 1 or 2 of the columns that are to be updated and not others. Either it succeeds to update all of them or fails for all.

Comment: Ikr, that's why I'm so confuse

Answer (score 0):

You are probably having problems with the update. `category_id` is presented on both tables, so when you make a join it will be "ambiguous".

Try to specify the table on `SET`, like `categories.category_id`.

Comment: still the sameee